# Session variable determining the selected option on a <select> form unsets itself on posting a local form?

Tags: php, html

I've been recently having a problem where I have the following:

- A drop down menu relating to values in the table.
- A PHP output that responds directly to the input from the drop down menu, referenced through an include.
- A form that, when posted to the main page, adds the input to an SQL table.

The aim is that when the form is posted, the data will immediately be added to the sidebar in which the PHP output resides. The problem I'm facing is that, upon the "update" form being posted to the main page, the session variable immediately unsets itself. I have no idea why it's doing this either.

Below I'm including the main PHP code in the head that is relevant to the data updating and session variable handling.

```
if ($_GET['newdata'] != "null") {
    $_SESSION['P_ID'] = $_GET['newdata'];
}
if (($_POST['date'] != "") and ($_POST['org'] != "") and ($_POST['imgno'] != "") and ($_POST['res'] != "") and ($_POST['pid'] != ""))  {
 $date = $_POST['date'];
 $org = $_POST['org'];   
 $imgno = $_POST['imgno'];
 $res = $_POST['res'];
 $pid = $_POST['pid'];
 $dsquery = "INSERT INTO Datasets (ProjectDate, Organism, ImageNumber, Resolution, ProjectID) VALUES ('$date', '$org', '$imgno', '$res', '$pid')";
 mysqli_query($db, $dsquery);
}
```

Here is the code on the original output form as well.

```
secure_session_start();
include_once("database.inc.php");
$db = ConnectDB();
echo "<div id=left-sidebar>
    <div class=datecontainer>";

$id = $_SESSION['P_ID'];

$datequery = "SELECT DISTINCT ProjectDate FROM Datasets WHERE ProjectID = '$id'";
#Validate Query here.

$result = mysqli_query($db,$datequery);
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $date = $row['ProjectDate'];
        $datasetquery = "SELECT DatasetNo, Organism, Resolution, ImageNumber FROM Datasets WHERE ProjectDate='$date' AND ProjectID = '$id'";

        $datasetresult = mysqli_query($db, $datasetquery);
        if ($datasetresult) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datasetresult)) {
                $setno = $row['DatasetNo'];
                $org = $row['Organism'];
                $imgno = $row['ImageNumber'];
                $res = $row['Resolution'];
                CreateDataset($date, $id, $res, $org, $setno, $imgno);
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "</div> </div>";

function CreateDataset($date, $id, $res, $org, $setno, $imgno) {
    for ($x=0; $x<count($setno); $x++){
        echo "<br><div class=\"date\">$date</div><div class=\"dataset\">
        <p><u>Dataset ".$setno."</u></p>
        <form action=\"\">
            <input type=\"radio\" name=\"rating\" value=\"red\"> Red
            <input type=\"radio\" name=\"rating\" value=\"amber\"> Amber
            <input type=\"radio\" name=\"rating\" value=\"green\"> Green
        </form>
        <table border=\"1\" align=\"center\">
                <tr>
                    <td>Organism</td>
                    <td>Image quantity</td>
                    <td>Resolution</td>
                    <td>Project ID</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$org</td>
                    <td>$imgno</td>
                    <td>$res</td>
                    <td>$id</td>
                </tr>
            </table>   
     </div>";
    }
}
```

[Note: secure_session_start() is a function.]

Finally, the drop down menu code:

```
    secure_session_start();
include_once("database.inc.php");
   ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/toolbar.css">
 <div id="Projects">
      <form action="main.php" method="get">
      <select name="newdata" id="projectselect" onchange="selectProject()">"
     <?php
        $db = ConnectDB();
        $sessquery = "SELECT * FROM Project WHERE ProjectID = $_SESSION[P_ID]";
        $sessresult = mysqli_query($db,$sessquery);
        if ($sessresult == TRUE) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sessresult)) {
                $sessid = $row['ProjectID'];
                $sessname = $row['ProjectName'];
                echo "<option select=selected value=\"$sessid\">$sessname</option>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<option select=selected value=null>Projects</option>";
        }
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Project";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
        if ($result == TRUE) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $id = $row['ProjectID'];
                $name = $row['ProjectName'];
                echo "<option value=\"$id\">$name</option>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<option>Query Error.</option>";
        }
     unset($result);
     mysqli_close;
     ?>
     <option value="addproject">Add new project.</option>
 </select>
    <input type=submit value="Access Project"/>
</form>
```

Apologies for the copious amounts of code, but I really have no idea as to why the session variable unsets itself without being told directly to do so.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: This is currently on a localhost SQL/PHP testing server. SQL Injections aren't _currently_ a priority

Comment: wrong attitude. it's VERY easy to write safe queries. you'll spend MORE time re-writing code to become safe, than you would ever have spent writing safe queries from the get-go.

Comment: AFAIK the code is only ever going to be used internally, but I see your point. I'm going to bear that in mind.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's for internal use only. You can trivially inject yourself. EVEN if it's not an "attack" - any SQL metacharacters in some string that you stuff into a query string will cause an sql syntax error and break your system.

Comment: Yeah. I can probably use something like str_replace() or mysqli*_real_escape_string() to sanitise my data input.

Comment: wrong again. you don't use mysql_*() anymore. it's deprecated and has been REMOVED from php. you use PDO/mysqli with placeholders and prepared statements. Manual sanitization is also a fool's game. you'll never get it right, and why should you have to worry about manual sanitization when the provided PROPER tools (prep statements/placeholders) take care of all the work for you?

Comment: Ok, that was a screwup on my end. I appreciate the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I actually managed to remedy my own problem oddly enough. What are the odds? :)

Take this piece of code:

```
if ($_GET['newdata'] != "null") {
$_SESSION['P_ID'] = $_GET['newdata'];
}
if (($_POST['date'] != "") and ($_POST['org'] != "") and ($_POST['imgno'] != "") and ($_POST['res'] != "") and ($_POST['pid'] != ""))  {
 $date = $_POST['date'];
 $org = $_POST['org'];   
 $imgno = $_POST['imgno'];
 $res = $_POST['res'];
 $pid = $_POST['pid'];
 $dsquery = "INSERT INTO Datasets (ProjectDate, Organism, ImageNumber, Resolution, ProjectID) VALUES ('$date', '$org', '$imgno', '$res', '$pid')";
 mysqli_query($db, $dsquery);
}
```

Considering that current ProjectID is posted alongside the if statement, I modified the code as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $_SESSION['P_ID'] = $_POST['pid'];
}
else{
    $_SESSION['P_ID'] = $_GET['newdata'];
}
```

This now keeps the output the same page and no longer unsets the variable. Sorry StackOverflow people, and thanks @Marc B for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this:

```
if ($_GET['newdata'] != "null") {
                        ^----^
```

unless you're passing in `example.com?newdata=null`, then you're not testing if that query value is an actual null (unknown) value, you're testing against a string which contains the letters `n`, `u`, `l`, and `l`.

Note the following:

```
php > var_dump(null == 'null');
bool(false)
```

Since an actual null is NOT equal to a string null, you blindly reset your session variable. If that `newdata` query parameter is NOT present, then you literally set your session variable to be an actual null.

You probably want something more like:

```
if(isset($_GET['newdata'])) {
   $_SESSION['P_ID'] = $_GET['newdata'];
}
```

Comment: Currently, this is the option referring to the null, will this refer to the string "null" or an actual null value: echo "<option select=selected value=null>Projects</option>";

Comment: EDIT: This hasn't changed anything unfortunately.

Comment: Set your `form action` to `htmlentities($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);`